# Errors in Eclipse executing Python program using Spark library

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, apache-spark

I was following this tutorial [here](http://enahwe.blogspot.com.es/p/philippe-rossignol-20150612-how-to.html) to configure eclipse for python programming using the Spark library. I followed step by step without any issue...

However, once I execute this sample program:

```
# Imports
# Take care about unused imports (and also unused variables),
# please comment them all, otherwise you will get any errors at the execution.
# Note that neither the directives "@PydevCodeAnalysisIgnore" nor "@UnusedImport"
# will be able to solve that issue.
#from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import os

# Configure the Spark environment
sparkConf = SparkConf().setAppName("WordCounts").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf = sparkConf)

     # The WordCounts Spark program
    textFile = sc.textFile(os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] + "/README.md")
    wordCounts = textFile.flatMap(lambda line: line.split()).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    for wc in wordCounts.collect(): print wc
```

I obtain a list of errors like this:

[image]

Do I have to modify any path or follow other configuration to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running pyspark shell in same directory where readme file is saved no need to give spark home path.

try removing spark home path and '/'.

```
textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")
```

or

```
textFile = sc.textFile(os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] + "README.md").
```

Define a split condition. space separated or '#' any value separated split

```
lambda line: line.split(" ")
```